# LDAP host changed. Can no longer login to Jenkins to reconfigure

Tags: ldap, jenkins

I set up Jenkins with LDAP sign in. Everything worked fine.
Now our IT department changed the LDAP host address, and therefore I can no longer sign in to Jenkins in order to change the LDAP host address.

What to do?

Comment: Is it possible to login using Jenkin's local account when LDAP server is not available ? Means can we use both Jenkin's local account and LDAP account to login ?

Answer (score 3):

Edit Jenkins' configuration file, e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins.config.xml`.
Change `$SOME_IP_OR_SOME_HOSTNAME` at the following part:

```
<hudson>
  ...
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm" ...>
    ...
    <server>$SOME_IP_OR_SOME_HOSTNAME</server>
    ...
  </securityRealm>
  ...
</hudson>
```

Then restart Jenkins, e.g. `sudo service jenkins restart`.